# Java Optional query string paramters and Server side API's

Tags: java, api

Here is my requirement:
Step Five: Add searching by title
This method's purpose is to enable searching by title. You'll pass in an optional query string parameter that returns all auctions with the search term in the title.

In AuctionController.java, return to the list() action method. Add a String request parameter with the name title_like. You'll need to make this parameter optional, which means you set a default value for it in the parameter declaration. In this case, you want to set the default value to an empty string "".

Look in MemoryAuctionDao.java for a method that returns auctions that have titles containing a search term. Return that result in the controller method if title_like contains a value, otherwise return the full list like before.

My code that is NOT passing is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "title_like = ", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Auction> searchByTitle(@RequestBody String title_like) {
    if (!title_like.isEmpty()) {
        for (Auction auction : auctions) {
            if (dao.searchByTitle(title_like).contains(title_like)) {
                auctions.add(auction);
                return auctions;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: why there is an equal sign in the value field, and why did you annotated the "title_like", with @RequestBody, it is a request param right ?

Comment: @MaxExplode I updated to RequestParam...but still not passing..will keep on working on it. New to Java and API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor the code like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<List<Auction>> searchByTitle(@RequestParam(name="title_like", required=false) String title_like) {
            ...
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body(<body>).build();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using GET method. With Get, it contain no body.

That why your signature don't work.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "title_like = ", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Auction> searchByTitle(@RequestBody String title_like)
```

So you have to change @RequestBody to @RequestParam with GET method.

```
@RequestParam(name="title_like", required=false) String title_like
```

Other ways, you can change to different method to support body like (RequestMethod.POST, PUT...).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "title_like = ", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<Auction> searchByTitle(@RequestBody String title_like)
```

Comment: Thank you all! I am not sure how to close my question. I am good now.

Comment: Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, you can upvote and accept the answers... It will be motive for answeres